# How to solve Apache Proxy Error 502 (Error Reading From Remote Server)

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I never received proper instruction on using a proxy in apache, and have mainly been managing by myself so far. Could really use some help with this error.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot ...

    ServerName ...
    SSLCertificateFile ...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf


ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyVia Full
 <Proxy *>
 Require all granted
 </Proxy>

<Location /test1>
 ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3001/
 ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3001
 </Location>

<Location /test2>
 ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
 ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000
 </Location>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The issue is that I receive the above error code for /test2/ but not /test1/. Thanks to anyone who has advice.

Comment: Use slash in `ProxyPassReverse` `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`. Also, share your error and access log in question.

Comment: Yes slashes no slashes no difference, I believe the issue is SSL.

Comment: Then it should not work for test1.Share error log snippet.